# CountDownTimer Pause

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a countdowntimer in my app. Whenever i click the imageview, it should pause for 10seconds and automatically start after 10 seconds. I am using the codes below. Its not working ! How can i make it possible?

MainActivity.java:

```js
package app.thesis.boogleit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 //VARIABLES by AL
 DBAdapter dbHelper;
 EditText words, scores, search;
 ImageView show_addWord;
 TextView score, tv2, tv3;
 //GAMEPLAY by LOVELY
 protected static final String TAG = null;
 String generatedString = " ";
 AutoCompleteTextView text;
 TextView timer;
 ImageView searchWord;
 ImageView blizzard, bomb, searchword, lineone;
 ImageButton image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8,
 image9, image10, image11, image12, image13, image14, image15, image16;
 ListView wordList;
 private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
 private boolean timeHasStarted = false;
 
 
 
    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        dbHelper =new DBAdapter(this);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
        words = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);
        scores = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edScore);
        show_addWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_addWord);
                
        show_addWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //buttonSound.start();
    startActivity(new Intent("app.thesis.boggleit.ADDWORD")); 
   }
  });
        
        
        blizzard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blizzard);
        bomb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bomb);
        searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
  image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
  image3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
  image4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
  image5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button5);
  image6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button6);
  image7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button7);
  image8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button8);
  image9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button9);
  image10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
  image11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
  image12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
  image13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button13);
  image14 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button14);
  image15 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button15);
  image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);

  timer = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
  timer.setText("00:00:30");
  countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000,1000);
  
  final AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
  
  final ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
  
 //array of images  
  final int[] myPics = { };
  //random images 
  
  //pause time and resume time automatically
  blizzard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
    if (!timeHasStarted) {
     countDownTimer.cancel();
     timeHasStarted = false; 
        
        }
    else {
     countDownTimer.start();
        timeHasStarted = true;
         }
    
   
   }
  });
  
        
  bomb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
  //random image 
        }
  });
  
  
  //click imgbuttons> display text in txtview > start countdounttimer
  
  OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
                
                if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.a){
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
                    generatedString=generatedString+"a"; //[PLACEE RESPACTIVE CHARACTEER HERE]
                    text.setText(generatedString);
                    
           
            if (!timeHasStarted) {
                countDownTimer.start();
                timeHasStarted = true;
                }
         

   }
   
  };

  
  
  image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
    }
    

//Countdowntimer
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
  public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
   super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   long millis = millisUntilFinished;  
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),  
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),  
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));  
            System.out.println(hms);  
            timer.setText(hms);  
   
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   timer.setText("Time's Up!");
  }
 }
    
    
// search word on db > display score in 2 textview    
    private int optionTxtView = 0  ;
    

public void viewWord(View view)
    {
//     String data= dbHelper.getAllData();
  //   Message.message(this, data);
     score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourScore);
     tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        
        searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
     
     String s1= search.getText().toString();
        String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1);
        //Message.message(this, s2); 
        
      
     if(optionTxtView == 0){
            //display the score on textview1
      score.setText(s2);
      tv2.setText(s2);
      optionTxtView = 1;
      }else{
            //display the score on textview2    
            tv3.setText(s2);
            optionTxtView = 0;
      }
     
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        wordList.setAdapter(adapter);    
     adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        text.setText("");
     
        
        }
}
```

Comment: what are you using the timer for? Post some more code/explanation

Comment: also, from your code, why do you want to stop/cancel the timer if timeHasStarted is false? I don't think that is going to achieve anything meaningful

Comment: My app needs a pause in timer. So I have to know how to pause the countdowntimer. I already edited my codes. @Hahn

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use a `Handler` and a `Runnable`

declare it like this:

```
private static Handler handler = new Handler();
private int totalTimeToRun = 30;//in seconds
private Runnable timerHandler = new Runnable() {
    public int runnableCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

       handler.removeCallbacks(this);
       //do what the timer is supposed to do when it runs
       if(runnableCount == 30) {
          //30 seconds are up
          //reset
          runnableCount = 0;//so we can reuse it

       } else {    
          //update the time values
          //time left in seconds = 30-runnableCount       
          handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);//every second
       }
       runnableCount++;
    }
}
```

Whenever there is a need to 'pause' the timer, just call the following:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(timerHandler);
```

to 'resume' the timer, just call the following:

```
handler.post(timerHandler);
```

Hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Where would i put those? Can you help me using my codes?